# How do you change the default colorscheme in gvim?

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

In GVIM for Windows I know you are supposed to be able to add something to the `$VIM/_vimrc` file in order to customize the start up and I have managed how to figure out a few neat tricks with that but I can't figure out how to change the default color settings.  Right now every time I start vim, I have to type

```
:color pablo
```

before I can do any work (black on white bothers me when coding in anything but Java).  I feel like this is 12 extra keystrokes I shouldn't have to be making every time I start vim.  Is there a way I can have vim start using this setting by default?

Comment: In Ubuntu make a file with the name `.vimrc` in your `Home` directory if it doesn't exist, add `colorscheme pablo` in it and save it. Now restart GVim. For Windows put this file with the name `_gvimrc` in `C:/Documents and Settings/<your-username>`. See eckes answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136751/load-vimrc-for-gvim-in-windows-and-change-font-and-colors).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add

```
colorscheme pablo
```

to your _vimrc file.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.  I couldn't find it anywhere in the help documents but maybe I wasn't looking hard enough this is a huge burden of my OCD mind.

Answer (score 3):

nagnatron's answer is right, but if you need a little more information ...

["A Byte of Vim"](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/vim/) is a book which aims to help you to learn how to use the Vim editor, even if all you know is how to use the computer keyboard.

Comment: Generally it is best to add to an existing answer as a comment rahter than as a separate answer.

Comment: Wow this is one of the most useful links I've seen in a while thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was necessary to do:

```
"~\_vimrc

if has('gui_running')
  au VimEnter * colorscheme desert
endif
```

The `if has('gui_running')` makes sure I keep the default color settings if I'm running vim in **Cmder (conemu)**.
My setup may be funny though, I have vim installed by **scoop** (a package manager for windows I recommend you check out if you haven't heard of it).

Comment: A potentially better option for your gui-specific Vim settings may be to put them in the [`.gvimrc`](https://vimhelp.org/gui.txt.html#gvimrc) (or `_gvimrc` on Windows) file.